# MFC newbie: how to determine if a character is hexadecimal using "FindOneOf()"

Tags: c++, mfc, std

I'm new at MFC and I need to do something which sounds extremely simple: determining if a string only contains hexadecimal characters.

For that, I browse through the string (it's a `CString`) and I verify all characters using the `FindOneOf()` method, as follows:

```
int iTest = CString(pszText[i]).FindOneOf((LPCWSTR)"0123456789ABCDEFabcdef");
```

For some bizarre reason, I always get `-1` as a result.

What am I doing wrong?

P.s.1 I prefer not to use the `SpanIncluding()` method, I find the `FindOneOf()` quite readable but I don't know how to use it.
P.s.2 Also simple `STL` seems not to be working: I tried to work with `std::isxdigit(pszText[i])` but in order to get this to work, I need to include `<locale>` and then this function is asking for a second parameter, next to the character I want to check, and a `null`-pointer is not allowed there (`std::isxdigit(pszText[i], nullptr)` does not work).

Comment: That "bizarre reason" is likely related to that highly suspicious cast to `LPCWSTR`. How about we fix that first. If you're using unicode strings, use a unicode literal: `L"0123456789ABCDEFabcdef"`, and lose that cast. You don't fix bugs by hiding their warnings/errors with casts.

Comment: You don't need to include ``<locale>`` to get ``std::isxdigit``. There is a locale-less version: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/isxdigit. Your problem is probably that you have wide-characters (hence your cast to ``LPCWSTR``) instead of single characters. So you would need to use ``std::iswxdigit``.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several problems in your code:

This is wrong:

```
int iTest = CString(pszText[i]).FindOneOf(LPCWSTR)"0123456789ABCDEFabcdef");
```

It should be:

```
int iTest = CString(pszText[i]).FindOneOf(L"0123456789ABCDEFabcdef");
```

The cast will simply make the compiler believe that `"0123..."` is a wide string but it isn't. You need to use the `L` prefix to indicate that the string is a wide string.

But even then your algorithm won't work because `FindOneOf` will simply find the first occurrence of any of the characters in the parameter.

Example:

```
int iTest = CString(L"Z223Zbc").FindOneOf(L"0123456789ABCDEFabcdef");
```

`"Z223Zbc"` is obviously not a hexadecimal string, but `iTest` will contain 1 because the first character of `"Z223Zbc"` being part of `"0123456789ABCDEFabcdef"` is `'2'` and that's at position 1.

`iTest` will only contain -1 if the string to be tested doesn't contain *any* hexadecimal characters as for example `"xyz"`.

Therefore this solution is appropriate:

```
  #include <cwctype>
  ...
  WCHAR string[] = L"123abcX";
  bool ishexstring = true;    // assume the string is a hex string
  for (int i = 0; ; i++)
  {
    WCHAR c = string[i];
    if (c == 0)
      break;                  // end of string => we exit the looop
    if (!std::iswxdigit(c))
    {
      ishexstring = false;    // c is no hex digit
      break;                  // exit loop
    }
  }
```

This algorithm should be put into a function, but I'm leaving this as an exercise for the reader.

Solution using `SpanIncluding` (less efficient because we need tot construct a temporary `CString`):

```
bool ishexstring = CString(string).SpanIncluding(L"0123456789ABCDEFabcdef") == str;
```

Comment: @Dominique OK, but using `FindOneOf` is absolutely overkill anyway, just use `std::iswxdigit(c)` which does exactly what you want.